# Split data across multiple workbooks depending on column value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has some 100,000+ number of lead records. Each record has an agent code which determines to whom the record is allotted to(50 plus agents). What I would like to do is to distribute all lead records per agent(workbook) depending on the agent code while also maintaining the existing data formatting, data validation and also automatically creating a worksheet password. Is this possible with excel VBA?

The table runs by this sequence:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt7KN.png)

EDIT:
Here are some of the sample scripts we ran:

```
Sub ExtractToNewWorkbook()

    Dim ws     As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew  As Workbook
    Dim rData  As Range
    Dim rfl    As Range
    Dim state  As String
    Dim sfilename As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("emp")

    'Apply advance filter in your sheet

    With ws
        Set rData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp))

        .Columns(.Columns.Count).Clear

        .Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter _
                        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                        CopyToRange:=.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), _
                        Unique:=True


        For Each rfl In .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).End(xlUp))

             state = rfl.Text
             Set wsNew = Workbooks.Add

             sfilename = state & ".xlsx"

             'Set the Location
             ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sfilename

             Application.DisplayAlerts = False
             ws.Activate

             rData.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=state
             rData.Copy
             Windows(state).Activate
             ActiveSheet.Paste
             ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

        Next rfl

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End With

    ws.Columns(Columns.Count).ClearContents

    rData.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is all possible with VBA. What have you tried so far?

Comment: We've tried multiple modules provided by the generous community. However, the main problem is how to include password protecting the worksheet and maintaining the data validations and formatting present on the master file whenever it gets written to another workbook. For reference, here are links to some modules we ran:

Comment: https://yodalearning.com/tutorials/how-to-split-spreadsheet-into-separate-workbooks-using-excel-vba/
https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-fast-means-to-split-an-excel-worksheets-contents-into-multiple-workbooks-based-on-a-specific-column/

Comment: Voted to reopen based on the latest edit.

Comment: Can you post a before and after sample?  Show what you see before the code runs and show what you want to see after the code runs.  Thanks.